# How to translate SQL to DAX, Need to add FILTER

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to create calculated table that will summarize `In_Force` Premium from existing table `fact_Premium`.

How can I filter the result by saying:

```
TODAY() has to be between `fact_Premium[EffectiveDate]` and (SELECT TOP 1 fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] ORDE BY QuoteID DESC)
```

In SQL I'd do that like this:

```
    `WHERE CONVERT(date, getdate()) between CONVERT(date, tblQuotes.EffectiveDate) 
and (
      select top 1 q2.ExpirationDate 
        from Table2 Q2 
        where q2.ControlNo = Table1.controlno 
        order by quoteid` desc
       )
```

---

Here is my DAX statement so far:

```
In_Force Premium = 
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
           //Grouping necessary columns
            fact_Premium,
            fact_Premium[QuoteID],
            fact_Premium[Division],
            fact_Premium[Office],
            dim_Company[CompanyGUID],
            fact_Premium[LineGUID],
            fact_Premium[ProducerGUID],
            fact_Premium[StateID],
            fact_Premium[ExpirationDate]
                  ),    
            "Premium", CALCULATE(
                                SUM(fact_Premium[Premium])
                                ),
            "ControlNo", CALCULATE(
                            DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_Premium[ControlNo])
                                  )

   ), // Here I need to make sure TODAY() falls between fact_Premium[EffectiveDate] and (SELECT TOP 1 fact_Premium[ExpirationDate] ORDE BY QuoteID DESC)
    )
```

Also, what would be more efficient way, to create calculated table from fact_Premium or create same table using sql statement (--> Get Data--> SQL Server) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 potential ways in T-SQL to get the next effective date. One is to use `LEAD()` and another is to use an `APPLY` operator. As there are few facts to work with here are **samples**:

```
select *
from (
      select *
      , lead(EffectiveDate) over(partition by CompanyGUID order by quoteid desc) as NextEffectiveDate
      from Table1
      join Table2 on ...
     ) d
```

or

```
select table1.*, oa.NextEffectiveDate
from Table1
outer apply (
    select top(1) q2.ExpirationDate AS NextEffectiveDate
    from Table2 Q2 
    where q2.ControlNo = Table1.controlno 
    order by quoteid desc
     ) oa
```

nb. an `outer apply` is a little similar to a `left join` in that it will allow rows with a NULL to be returned by the query, if that is not needed than use `cross apply` instead.

In both these approaches you may refer to `NextEffectiveDate` in a final where clause, but I would prefer to avoid using the convert function if that is feasible (this depends on the data).